# selecting unicode characters from text file or webpage

Tags: python

I am able to syllabalise the devnagari words as shown on the following page.

https://gist.github.com/950405

But what I want to do is to find the words those start with "ह" from the following webpage.

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs12030.htm

How it can done using python?

Comment: Look into the beautifulsoup package, which is designed for working with HTML documents.  Using it to search for Devanagari text should not be any different than for English text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your words are unicode strings, collected in a list `words`, then the following snippet shows you all words beginning with `"x"`

```
for word in words:
    if word.startswith(u"x"):
         print word
```

Or if you want to get a list of all words starting with `u"x"`, you can use list comprehension:

```
selected_words = [ w for w in words if w.startswith(u"x") ]
```